# Disabling UIPanGestureRecognizer of UITableView programmatically

Tags: uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

In my `UIViewController` I have a `UITableViewController` (filling up the whole screen) and a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`. I want to disable the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the table when the user is panning at the edge of the screen.

I can solve this problem by using `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` but it just doesn't feel right being able to pan the table vertically and activating the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`.

So I was trying to set the delegate of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the table to self and disable it when a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` is occurring by using:

```
if let recognizers = tableView.gestureRecognizers {
    if let index = find(recognizers.map { $0 is UIPanGestureRecognizer }, true) {
        (recognizers[index] as UIPanGestureRecognizer).delegate = self
    }
}
```

This is giving me an exception saying: `'UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate.'`

Is there another way to disable the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, but not sure if this is the way it should be done:

```
if let recognizers = tableView.gestureRecognizers {
    if let index = find(recognizers.map { $0 is UIPanGestureRecognizer }, true) {
        (recognizers[index] as UIPanGestureRecognizer).requireGestureRecognizerToFail(screenEdgeGesture)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `userInteractionEnabled` on the view.

Comment: I've tried using `scrollEnabled = false` if recognizer is `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` in `shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer` but I have no means to turn it back to true here. So if i disable it, where should I enable it again if I just tap the screen edge? It will change `scrollEnabled` to false but doesn't get to `state == .Ended`.